# Can I populate list items in a ASP.NET dropdown list from a ASP.NET Placeholder?

Tags: asp.net, templates, drop-down-menu, placeholder

I'm designing my own custom control that contains a .NET dropdownlist. What I'm wondering is if it is possible to populate my dropdownlist with listitems placed in a placeholder?

For example:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFilter" runat="server" >
  <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ListItemPlaceholder" runat="server"/>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

This doesn't work because the DropDownList control only allows ListItems as child controls. But, I want to do something similar to this so when the user includes my control on a page, they can do something like this:

```
<mytag:MyControl Mode="DropDown" runat="server">
    <ListItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="c"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="E" Value="e"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="b"></asp:ListItem>
    </ListItemTemplate>
</myTag:MyControl>
```

Any suggestions or ideas? I know I can do this by dynamically adding the ListItems in the page code behind, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach to this would be to give your control a [`[ParseChildren(true, "ListItemTemplate")]` attribute.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute.aspx)

If you then had a property called "`ListItemTemplate`", which was an array of `ListItems`, your markup would be parsed into that property.  At runtime in your control, you could simply hand your dropdownlist the contents of that property.

Some non-tested example code:

```
   [ParseChildren(true, "ListItemTemplate")]
   public class MyControl: Control
   {  
      private ArrayList employees = new ArrayList();
      private DropDownList myDropDownList = new DropDownList();

      public ArrayList ListItemTemplate
      {
         get 
         {
            return employees;
         }
      }

      protected override void CreateChildControls()
      { 
         myDropDownList.Items.AddRange(ListItemTemplate):
         Controls.Add(myDropDownList);
      }
   }
```

Comment: Nice.  Never seen this before.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I had to make a couple modifications, but your basic idea worked like a charm.